# Android Studio: Have app access the users app drawer

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make an app that can enable/disable the auto rotate feature on certain apps. 
I have no idea if it's even possible to tell my app to access the users "App Drawer" to select certain apps. It's hard to explain but the best example that i can think of makes sense if you have used Tasker. In Tasker, when you start a new profile it brings up "Application" "Day" "Event" etc. and when you select "Application" a big grid menu pops up with all of the Apps that are in the users phone and it's titled "App Selection" I want to use something exactly like this but have no idea about how to go about it. Any advice would be appreciated or a link to any video that might help. Thank you very much for reading this!

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to make an app that prevents other apps' activities from controlling their own orientation?

Comment: There is an app that does this, enable/disable the auto-rotate feature of certain apps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate It actually works. I've successfully used it on my Google TV for the apps that only wanted to display themselves in portrait mode. However, don't ask me how it works. My guess is, it's using some undocumented android apis, or some kind of dark magic. This kind of project is definitely not for beginners. And I'm only talking about the enabling/disabling of the rotate featue. The application drawer itself, that's the really easy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer part of your question.
1. To get the list of installed application you can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int))
2. You can then create a view in which you put them in a gridview of some sort. (Using Packagemanager you can get its icon, package name etc)